# CoreData update multiple objects

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm making RSS reader and I want to make feeds items can be marked as read. I'm using CoreData for my project.

My model:

[image]

RSSItemsTableViewController:

```
 class RSSItemsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var feedNavigationItem: UINavigationItem!

    var linkRSS: String = ""
    var feeds: [RSSFeedCoreData] = []
    var coreData = CoreDataModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        feeds = coreData.getDataRSSFeeds(selectRSS: selectedRSS!).sorted(by: {($0.timeCreate?.timeIntervalSince1970)! > $1.timeCreate!.timeIntervalSince1970}
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return feeds.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemFeedTableViewCell
        cell.feedTitle.text = feeds[indexPath.row].title
        cell.timeLabel.text = feeds[indexPath.row].timeCreate?.timeIntervalSinceNow.stringFromTimeInterval()
        cell.siteUrl.text = feeds[indexPath.row].siteUrl
        if let url = feeds[indexPath.row].imageUrl {
            cell.imageFeed.loadImage(from: url)
        } else {
            cell.widthImage.constant = 0
            cell.widthFromImage.constant = 0
            cell.widthFromImageSite.constant = 0
        }
        return cell
    }

               }
}
```

And CoreData Model code:

```
class CoreDataModel {

    var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<RSSFeedCoreData>?        

    func getDataRSSFeeds(selectRSS: RSSCoreData) -> [RSSFeedCoreData] {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        var RSSdataFeed: [RSSFeedCoreData] = []

        do {
            let RSSdata: [RSSCoreData] = try context.fetch(RSSCoreData.fetchRequest())
            RSSdataFeed = RSSdata[RSSdata.index(of: selectRSS)!].feeds?.allObjects as! [RSSFeedCoreData]
        }
        catch {
            RSSdataFeed = []
        }
        return RSSdataFeed
    }
            }
}
```

I want to add button to RSSItemsTableViewController to make loaded RSS items as read (read item in CoreData  should be updated for true value for all feed items). How this can be done with CoreData?

Comment: I know this comment doesn't answer your question, but I would avoid adding `CoreData` as a suffix to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ItemFeedTableViewCell`, store the `ManagedObjectID` of the `RSSFeed` object when you create the cell.  Then later, when you click the `read` button on your custom `ItemFeedTableViewCell`, just simply use that `ManagedObjectID` to lookup the record in the `RSSFeed` table and set the `read` value to `YES`.

Comment: Thank your for you answer. May be you can provide also sample code how this can be done?